# How to correctly resize a View so its bottom is aligned with other View's top in ConstraintLayout programatically?

Tags: java, android

I have a ScrollView and a FrameLayout inside a ConstraintLayout. When I click a button, I want the ScrollView layout to resize so the bottom of the ScrollView is aligned with the top of the FrameLayout. However, the constraints won't change when the button is clicked.

I've tried to put the ScrollView inside a LinearLayout instead, but that didn't work either.

When button is clicked:

```java
private void fixTableConstraint() {
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.home_constraint_layout);
        View scrollView = findViewById(R.id.homeScreenScroll);
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();

        constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
        constraintSet.connect(R.id.homeScreenScroll, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.timeMenuOverlay, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
        constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);

        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams cl = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        scrollView.setLayoutParams(cl);
}
```

XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/homeScreenScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/homescreenTable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </ScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/timeMenuOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="152dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/timeMenuFragment"
            android:name="multicus.com.scheduleplannerv2.TimeMenuFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Normal Layout:
https://imgur.com/VsfSgVa

What happens in my case when button is clicked:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmHg1.jpg

What I actually want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztTZs.jpg

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraints changes will not work because you have

`ScrollView` `layout_height` = `"match_parent"`

You can do it like this

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/homeScreenScroll"
    android:background="@color/green_dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"            // this is important
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/timeMenuOverlay" // and this
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <TableLayout
        ...
     />
</ScrollView>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/timeMenuOverlay"
    android:visibility="gone"               // !!
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="152dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
```

Instead of changing your layout constraints, change only the visibility.

`timeMenuOverlay` visibility => `GONE`, expand your ScrollView to the bottom

`timeMenuOverlay` visibility => `VISIBLE` => expected result